# How do I tweak this program so it prints the largest negative integer?

Tags: python, integer

The program below is supposed to print the largest integer entered by the user, but it only works for positive integers.

How can I make a small tweak so it works with negative integers and prints the number entered by the user closest to zero?

The exercise I am attempting does not permit the use of lists or max functions. I understand it is just a small change that is required. Grateful for any help

```
m = 0
finished = False
while not finished:
    print("Enter another integer number (0 to finish): ", end = "")
    s = input()
    num = int(s)
    if num != 0:   
        if num > m:
        m = num   
    else:
        finished = True
print(str(m))
```

Comment: What is the program supposed to do? Can you give examples of inputs and expected outputs? What if you feed positive and negative numbers?

Comment: The code shown works for all integers. If the result is supposed to disregard positive integers, then you need to check if `num` is positive and "ignore" it.

Comment: *Largest negative* could mean the negative number with the largest absolute value, or the negative number closest to zero.

Comment: @guidot Not really; the former is usually described as "most negative".

Comment: If you need the largest absolute values, use `abs(num)`, or a conditional `num if num>0 else -num`. In any case, please clarify. Also fix your indentation.

Comment: You also don't need the print and input separated, just use `s = input("Enter another integer number (0 to finish): "`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the largest negative integer in the case of the smallest? e.g. of -51, -12 and -25 it gives you -51.

If so you can change your> sign to <

```
    if num != 0:    
        if num < m:
            m = num
```

If you're looking for the largest negative integer in the case of the number closest to zero. e.g. of -51, -12 and -25 it gives you -12.

Then you can keep your code the same but add num<0 to ensure it is a negative number.

```
    if num != 0:   
        if num > m and num < 0:
            m = num
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Might want to fix the indentation. This code will raise an indentation error.

Comment: Good point, the solution has been updated

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is just to get the number with the minimum/negative number with largest absolute value, just switch the ">" with "<" :

```
m = 0
finished = False
while not finished:
    print("Enter another integer number (0 to finish): ", end = "")
    s = input()
    num = int(s)
    if num != 0:   
        if num < m:
            m = num   
    else:
        finished = True
print(str(m))
```

However, if you are looking for the number with the largest absolute value, maybe you should consider comparing abs( each number ) :

```
m = 0
finished = False
while not finished:
    print("Enter another integer number (0 to finish): ", end = "")
    s = input()
    num = int(s)
    if num != 0:   
        if abs(num) > abs(m):
            m = num   
    else:
        finished = True
print(str(m))
```

Answer (score 0):

David, If I got your question correctly, then you can simply make below changes to get it worked:

```
m = 0
finished = False
while not finished:
s = input("Enter another integer number (0 to finish): " , end = "")
        if s!= 0:   
        if s < m:
        m = s   
    else:
        finished = True
print(str(m))
```

Feel free to ask, if you want anything else apart from this.

Comment: Apologies I poorly worded my question and have reworded above - I am trying to edit the program so it prints the negative integer entered by the user closest to zero

Comment: @DavidMills, with the above code, if user entered negative value, it will print, if user entered 0 or positive value, then finished.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I was not clear in my initial post or made some errors in terms of forum etiquette (first post, Python beginner - bear with me).
I believe I have now got some working code which calculates the highest integer, both negative and positive. I thought there was a simple tweak but this is the best I can come up with.

```
finished = False
m = int(input("Enter an integer number: "))

while not finished:
  num = int(input("Enter another integer number (0 to finish): "))
  if num != 0:
    if num > m:
      m = num
      
  else:
    finished = True

print(str(m))
```

Comment: Try not to use the 'Answer' section for follow up posts. Instead, update your original post or use the comment section underneath.